# Add few seconds to repeating time data in a column to make them unique

Tags: google-sheets

I have a set of timestamped data in a table of a Google Sheet. In the "Time" column, some of them are repeating. (see the image below)

[image]

[link to google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cybu92HIKcaRlaF-XEHyTXysHcRWnuYG34WjALIkYoQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Help me to create the "new time column" with the following conditions:

1. If the time (in column 1) is repeating, add "120/number of times it repeats" (seconds) to the first one and 2*(120/number of times it repeats) and so on.
2. if the time (column 1) is not repeating add 1 minute to it.

(I have manually entered few data to "new time column" to explain my requirement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for the data shown:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(countif(A2:A22,A2:A22)=1,A2:A22+1/(24*60),
A2:A22+2/(24*60)/countif(A2:A22,A2:A22)*(row(A2:A22)-match(A2:A22,A2:A22,0))))
```

[image]